# using free(const char *) in c++ 11

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind, eclipse-cdt

In one of my c++ functions I am calling ab demangle. I want to deallocate result after changing that to string. Here is the code:

```
const char *  realName;
string name;
const std::type_info &ti = typeid(*this);
realName = abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &status);

name= realName;
int index =name.find_last_of(':');
name = name.substr(index+1, name.length()-index-1);
free((void *) realName);
```

The code is running without problem but eclipse compiler is not happy and showing an error for using free: "Function 'free' could not be resolved".

I tried to use delete instead of free.

```
delete realName;
```

The code is running without problem and eclipse compiler is happy, however when I am profiling code with valgrind, I am getting a profiling error: 
Mismatched free() / delete / delete []

So my question is:
1- Should I use free in c++ or shall I use just delete, delete []
2- If I should not use free why valgrind giving me an error
3- If I should use free why eclipse cdt comipler is giving me a compile error but when I am running code everything is ok.
4- is my code has correct style based on c++11? or is it a combination of c and old c++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I use `free` in C++ or shall I use just `delete`, `delete[]`?

You should use the function or the operator that matches the allocation. When you allocate memory for your own use, you should use `new`/`new[]` for allocation, and `delete`/`delete[]` for deallocation.

When the memory to be deallocated comes from other sources, such as `__cxa_demangle`, you should read the documentation to see what functionality needs to be used on deallocation. The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) for your function states that

> the demangled name is placed in a region of memory allocated with `malloc`.

Therefore, you must use `free` to free it.

> If I should use `free` why Eclipse cdt compiler is giving me a compile error but when I am running code everything is OK.

Function `free` is defined in [`<cstdlib>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) header. You need to add this header to your cpp file to make sure you code compiles fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shall I use <cstdlib> or <stdlib.h>? Why code run without problem in eclipse but it showed compile error in eclipse?

Comment: @Govan In C++ `<cstdlib>` header corresponds to `<stdlib.h>` of C.

Comment: `<cstdlib>` guarantees `std::free` to exist, `<stdlib.h>` guarantees `free` to exist (in a global namespace), it's not guaranteed to work the other way round

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `free` as the documentation says use `free`.

Perhaps you need to include the correct header file and library.
`#include <stdlib.h>` and maybe `-lC`